# Fusion Drive, Bootcamp and FileVault - with working Recovery HD?

Tags: bootcamp, macos, filevault, fusion-drive, recovery-hd

since I experimented a lot on this issue without coming to a solution, I hope someone else could help me with it.

I've got currently running a setup with those partitions:

- Fusion Drive (Mavericks)
- Windows (Windows 7 Ultimate 64)
- Recovery HD

`diskutil list`

gives me the standard output for Apple-made and self-made Fusion Drives with recovery HD:

```
Andys-Macbook-Pro:~ Andy$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         511.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         845.3 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows 7               154.0 GB   disk1s4
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X               *1.4 TB     disk2
```

Here's the problem: When I boot with alt I can't access the recovery HD, which I understand is common. But also using Command-R doesn't boot the recovery HD, instead it starts Internet Recovery (which should start on Command-Alt-R?!) All features like Find my Mac or FileVault 2 (FileVault's encrypting as I write) work just fine as far as I can see. My MacBook is located correctly and I can play a sound on the Mac from iCloud.com, so I guess it works just the way it should. Everything else works fine, too.

I don't really need my Recovery HD, because I also got another external recovery partition on an USB Stick. But I would be glad to know about what's the issue here, especially since it makes me feel crumbly to have an encrypted drive which relys on a not correctly installed Recovery HD by using CoreStorage. Running on a correct setup would make me feel a lot better ;)

I installed it by the following steps:
[DIY Fusion Drive: Adding Recovery HD to a CoreStorage Volume Group](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70472/diy-fusion-drive-adding-recovery-hd-to-a-corestorage-volume-group)
(First made install on HD to create Recovery HD, then merging Full SSD and HDD partition, recovering backup from CCC)

What I also do know is it's important to setup BootCamp prior FileVault. I restored my Windows 7 from a Winclone Image, since that is much more convenient, than installing Windows and all the utilities you need every time. I'm also very sure that this isn't causing the issue.

Im using a MacBook Pro 9,1 (mid 2012, non Retina) with a 512 GB Samsung 840 Pro in Optibay using OWC Data Doubler and 1 TB WD Scorpio Blue in Drivebay. I've got 2 SATA III ports, so it seemed better to leave the HD in Drivebay to avoid noise and keep the Sudden Motion Sensor working...
Also got a 16 GB RAM upgrade when I got my SSD in March, but I don't think thats important though.

So whats the solution for this mess?

3 additional questions:

1. Will I be able to boot to Recovery HD using FileVault (assuming it works properly)? If it works after the encryption, I wouldn't make an effort to fix it...
2. Will the second Boot Device which boots OS X which is there because of Fusion Drive usually disappear after encryption ist done?
3. Can Windows booted from a device in optibay (My first setup when I got my SSD was: 2 partitions on SSD, one for the Fusion Drive and one for Windows, to get that fast, too. But I couldn't work it out to boot, it always gave me the "no bootable device" error. Some others have stated though, When installed in the Drivebay, a Windows installation can be put back into optibay after that and works fine: [Windows will not boot to my boot camp partition on a DIY fusion drive - gives "No bootable device found" error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76821/windows-will-not-boot-to-my-boot-camp-partition-on-a-diy-fusion-drive-gives-n))

EDIT:
bless -info -verbose gives me:

```
Andys-Macbook-Pro:~ Andy$ bless -info -verbose
EFI found at IODeviceTree:/efi
Current EFI boot device string is: '<array><dict><key>IOMatch</key><dict><key>IOProviderClass</key><string>IOMedia</string><key>IOPropertyMatch</key><dict><key>UUID</key><string>2B1B626D-ECA3-45E0-B2C1-F9091B0BE3F4</string></dict></dict><key>BLLastBSDName</key><string>disk10s2</string></dict></array>'
Boot option is 8BE4DF61-93CA-11D2-AA0D-00E098032B8C:Boot0080
Processing boot option 'Mac OS X'
Boot option matches XML representation
Could not find disk device for string
Could not find network interface.
Firmware feature mask: 0xC003FF37
Firmware features: 0xC001F537
Legacy mode suppported
Boot option is not a legacy device
Could not interpret boot device as either network or disk
Can't interpet EFI boot device
```

I will try to rename the Recovery HD to "Boot OS X" but I've seen others which have called it recovery HD and it works just fine... 
How can a Core Storage operation relocate a Recovery partition, never heard of that?!

Comment: Drive is encrypted now, but still double Boot Drives when holding alt on startup and no access to the Recovery...

Comment: Nobody's got a hint for me? I'm highly motivated to make further experiments here to get it to work properly ^^

Comment: Still looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

[OS X Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718)
Mac models introduced after public availability of OS X Lion include the ability to start up directly from an Internet-based version of the OS X Recovery system. **OS X automatically uses this feature when the Recovery System on the hard disk isn't available** (such as when your hard disk encounters an issue, or when your hard disk has been replaced or erased).

My setup is a Mac mini 2011 with a DIY Fusion drive (840 Pro + 1 TB Hitachi). The Fusion drive was built on 10.8 and then the machine was  upgraded to 10.9.

```
diskutil list 
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         255.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         934.5 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                64.9 GB    disk1s4
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Fusion HD              *1.2 TB     disk2
```

1. When I press alt, I get three entries, Fusion, Fusion, Boot Camp. Either Fusion being selected boots the main OS. Bootcamp boots Windows.
2. ⌘R boots local Recovery HD (not Internet Recovery). I have a choice of Wi-Fi, if I need Internet Recovery.

In your case, is it possible the Recovery HD is damaged?

Comment: For all other features such sa "find my mac" it seems to. That's exactly why I'm confused ^^

Comment: *seems to work should it mean

Comment: How exactly did you build your fusion drive step by step? Same as I did?

Comment: The Fusion drive was built using http://jollyjinx.tumblr.com/post/34638496292/fusion-drive-on-older-macs-yes-since-apple-has

1. ML on SSD
2. Bootcamp on HDD
3. Remainder of HDD + entire SSD became Fusion drive using the mentioned link.

Comment: Okay, thats kind of weird since your Recovery HD (650 MB in size) is on you HDD as far as I see?! sure you didn't make an install of ML on the HDD before fusioning?

Comment: The Recovery HD was relocated by the system when I combined the SSD and the HDD.

Comment: In your case, from Terminal, please check what bless -info -verbose returns. In my case, it references "Boot OS X" on disk0s3 and disk1s3, both. This is a long shot, but does a volume name change (to "Boot OS X" from "Recovery HD") make any difference?

Comment: I edited my question, the terminal output was too long for a comment...

Comment: 1. If you boot using the Recovery HD on USB, what is sw_vers show in Terminal when booted? This is what I have from my internal Recovery HD  

ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9
BuildVersion: 13A603

2. Can you rebuild Recovery HD using http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848 on the internal drive (not on an external USB)?

Comment: I will check what sw_vers will give me. Have lent my Recovery USB to a friend over the weekend...
Recovery Disk Assistant sadly doesn't work for rebuilding an internal Recovery HD

Comment: Deleted contents of Mavericks partition, using Internet Recovery installed ML 10.8.5, verified ML Recovery, upgraded to Mavericks, verified Mavericks Recovery 10.9. Command+R works locally and Command+Opt+R for Internet Recovery also works. The same procedure **should** work on a Fusion Drive as well.

Comment: I understood you have a fusion drive, haven't you? If not, this wouldn't be helpful as for fusion drives the behavior of Recovery HDs is completely different

Comment: The local drive was converted to a CoreStorage volume using _diskutil cs convert_, but with just a single disk partition, not an SSD/HDD combination.

Comment: What scheme did you post above. That looks exactly like a Fusion Drive for me ô0

Comment: The second test was on a Fusion drive on a different machine with a single CoreStorage volume on a single HDD behind the CS volume. The _sw_vers_ being 10.9 is Mavericks on Recovery HD. Are you offered Mavericks when you attempt Internet Recovery or a different version of the OS?

Comment: So I checked what you told me: 1. Still only able to boot Internet Recovery: But after connecting to wifi it gives me an -1007F Error and I should contact Apple support. Well, because of the DIY fusion thats not really an option I think. 2. Also checked the sw_vers command on my external Recovery Stick: It's also 13A603, so this shouldn't be the problem. I tried now to delete and re-add an internal Recovery HD by cloning into an DMG, but all that has changed is, that one of the BootDrives showing on alt-hold on startup is now named "Recovery HD". That one still starts up normally like before.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see where you list your operating system version. According to this [ASN thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5101360), 1: you need 10.8.3 or later, and 2. there are still lots of problems reported using Fusion drives. Most everyone recommends using a VM instead.

Comment: Was using 10.8.5 and now 10.9. Every install etc was done with an up to date install media.

What has a Vm to do with a Fusion Drive?! ô0

Comment: VM would be MacOS - based. Boot Camp isn't, and there may be driver issues between the drive and Windows. That's speculating, but there are a lot of discussion threads on this issue.

Comment: The Samsung 840 Pro in general works perfectly fine with Windows, no doubt... Is that what you mean by driver issues?

Ok so you're referring to my third question. As I use Windows 7 for Gaming, a VM isn't really an alternative. It seems there are some issues booting windows not from the primary SATA slot (which is the original HD bay, of course). But I also read that some people got it to work to boot Win 7 from an SSD in optibay somehow, but didn't really understand what was the deciding factor. So if someone who did this would be able to clarify that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came to a unexpected resolution, I just saw I could clone my internal recovery HD with CCC from my external CCC Backup (where I cloned it to when I started the backup a few weeks ago). After that the Recovery HD worked properly, the second "Mac OS X" boot device on alt pressing on startup disappeared and it shows a "Wiederherstellung 10.9" instead. That boots the Recovery HD, CMD+R still boots Internet Recovery, but I'm fine with that :)

Comment: Interesting solution. CCC could have *bless* ed the Recovery HD as well. See this link - *http://help.bombich.com/kb/advanced-strategies/the-disk-center#recovery_hd* .

Comment: Not really sure what you mean?!